# Translating an add column operation from a dataframe to SQL

Tags: sql, r, pandas, dataframe

I will use Pandas here for this example but it should be applicable for any dataframe library. Pandas makes it quite pleasant to add on additional columns to an existing data frame. Here is the first example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df=pd.DataFrame(data={'col1':[1,2]})
>>> df['newCol']=df['col1']+1
>>> df
   col1  newCol
0     1       2
1     2       3
```

If we imagine we have a SQL table (df) with one column (col1) we could translate this to SQL with a row-calculation, something like:

```
SELECT col1, col1+1 AS newCol FROM df
```

I don't care about 'saving' the data to SQL, but only generating a query to get the new column. This is easy enough.

Now, let's take the second case where we have an existing table/column/list/etc. object, where the data is not derived by a table calculation. Here is the simplest example I can think of:

```
>>> pandas as pd
>>> df=pd.DataFrame(data={'col1':[1,2]})
>>> df['newCol'] = ['a','b']
>>> df
   col1 newCol
0     1      a
1     2      b
```

What would be the more direct way to translate this to SQL? To me it seems non-trivial, and would require joining on something like a row_id, and that doesn't yet take into account potentially different-sized table-objets. Using BigQuery as an example:

```
with df as (
  select 1 col1 union all select 2
),
df_with_row as (
  select *, row_number() over () as row_num from df
),
unnested_list as (
  select row_number() over () row_num, el from unnest(['a','b']) el
)
select df_with_row.* except(row_num), el from df_with_row left join unnested_list using(row_num)
```

Is there a better way to emulate this behavior of 'joining' an existing dataframe/table with a new column-like object which is implicitly joined on Row Number (unless an index is provided, here we'll pretend there's no index)

Comment: You realize that panda is python, sql is sql, and R has nothing to do with your post, right? am i missing something?

Comment: to me though, this is unnatural to SQL. SQL queries should be independent of (the length of) the data retrieved.

Comment: @RYann I'm trying to translate a dataframe concept to SQL, and I believe [Python's pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) and [R's data.frame](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/data.frame) are the two most popular libraries to do this?

Comment: You're trying to add a new column with arbitrary values to a table in SQL. I agree with others here, I don't think the Python example or the R tag add anything to this question. I wouldn't add an Excel tag to a question on how to pivot data in R just because it's popular to pivot data in Excel.

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using ?

Comment: What is the criteria that 1 joins to `a` and not `b`? What if number of rows mismatch?

Comment: @SalmanA it joins based on index (i.e., row number here). If the number of rows mismatch it will either (1) error; or (2) you can fill the 'shorter' item with null for all the missing items.

Comment: Are the values of `unnested_list` unique or you can have something like `['a', 'b', 'a']`? Does the order matter or you can have something like `[(1, 'b'), (2, 'a')]`?

Comment: @Corralien yes, order matters and the list elements are not guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example and the expected output, please?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to implicitly emulate the select query for that case. Please use this query

```
SELECT col1, newCol from (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over(order by (select 1)) AS rnum, df.col1 FROM (
        SELECT 1 AS col1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS col1
    ) df
) df
  JOIN (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over(order by (select 1)) AS rnum, df2.newCol FROM (
      SELECT 'a' AS newCol UNION ALL SELECT 'b' AS newCol
    ) df2
) df2 on df.rnum = df2.rnum
```

And if you wanted to use CTE approach here is the query

```
with df as (
  select 1 col1 union all select 2
),
df_with_row as (
  select *, row_number() over () as row_num from df
),
unnested_list as (
  select row_number() over () row_num, *  from (SELECT 'a' AS newCol UNION ALL SELECT 'b' AS newCol)
)
select col1, newCol from df_with_row left join unnested_list using(row_num)
```

Comment: are you using mysql5.7 or something or why all the repetition? This seems to be the same as my original query, using a SQL dialect that doesn't have access to a CTE.

Comment: Hi @David542, I am just using basic sql query here. You can test it at the link here https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/Le7

Comment: And if you want to use CTE approach you can try it at this link https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/Le9

Comment: Hi @David542, have this answered your question?

Answer (score -1):

```
select unnest(array[1, 2]), unnest(array['a' , 'b'])
```